# SQL: many to many relationships select where multiple criteria

Tags: mysql, sql

given these tables :

```
id_article | title
1          | super article
2          | another article

id_tag | title
1      | great
2      | awesome

id_relation | id_article | id_tag
1           | 1          | 1
2           | 1          | 2
3           | 2          | 1
```

I'd like to be able to select all articles that are "great" AND "awesome" (eventually, I'll probably have to implement OR too)

And basically, if I do a select on articles the relation table joining on id_article: of course, I cant join two different values of id_tag. Only lead I had with concatenating IDs to test as a string, but that seems so lame, there has to be a prettier solution.

Oh and if it matters, I use a MySQL server.

EDIT: for ByWaleed, the typical sql select that would surely fail that I cited  in my original question:

```
SELECT
    a.id_article,
    a.title
FROM articles a, relations r
WHERE
    r.id_article =  a.id_article and r.id_tag = 1 and r.id_tag = 2
```

wouldnt work because r.id_tag cant obviously be 1 and 2 on the same line. I doubt w3schools has an article on that. My search on google didnt yield any result, probably because I searched with the wrong keyword.

Comment: Would be great if you could update your question with the select statement that you have already tried.

Comment: I agree with @bilpor that you need to do some research first. Here is a good starting point: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp.

Comment: I described the select I did, and its inherent flaw : I cant discriminate vs two different things in the same row. Ill add it to the question for your viewing pleasure. as for your link, it's like sql joins 101, when I needed something like the two answers below gives : a new concept I never heard of, or couldnt find the keywords to find myself

Comment: @moo - you've only accepted answers to two of your questions ;)  To improve your standing in the community, you should go back and click some of the tick symbols to accept some answers ;)

Comment: @MatBailie oh ? no offense, but I dont really care about community standing ^^', moreover, I find it weird that the least qualified person (the one not knowing in the first place) should choose the best answer between what seems to be 3 valid answers. But if I really have to choose, I'll choose the first one, out of logic. Or may be yours, because you wrote about the OR aspect of the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you do all the joins as normal, then aggregate the rows to one group by article, then you can assert that they must have at least two different tags.

*(Having already filtered to `great` and/or `awesome`, that means they have both.)*

```
SELECT
    a.id_article,
    a.title
FROM
    articles a
INNER JOIN
    relations r
        ON r.id_article = a.id_article
INNER JOIN
    tags t
        ON t.id_tag = r.id_tag
WHERE
    t.title IN ('great', 'awesome')
GROUP BY
    a.id_article,
    a.title
HAVING
    COUNT(DISTINCT t.id_tag) = 2
```

*(The `DISTINCT` is to avoid the possibility of one article having `'great'` twice, for example.)*

To do `OR`, you just remove the `HAVING` clause.

Comment: Who down-voted, and why?  So I can address your concerns?

Comment: not me, my question was downvoted too, I suspect someone didnt read the whole question and thought it was a trivial sql join question (well, it's not trivial for me anyway). thank you for your answer

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to aggregate by article, and then assert that the article both the "great" and "awesome" tags:

```
SELECT
    a.id_article,
    a.title
FROM articles a
INNER JOIN relations r
    ON a.id_article = r.id_article
INNER JOIN tags t
    ON r.id_tag = t.id_tag
WHERE
    t.title IN ('great', 'awesome')
GROUP BY
    a.id_article,
    a.title
HAVING
    MIN(t.title) <> MAX(t.title);
```

[image]

### Demo

The logic here is that we first limit records, for each article, to only those of the two targets tags.  Then we assert, in the `HAVING` clause, that *both* tags appear.  I use a `MIN`/`MAX` trick here, because if the min and max differ, then it implies that there are two distinct tags.

Comment: I'll try in that direction and MatBailie's one to begin with, I didnt see that kind of approach, I mean "inflating" testing and grouping

Comment: @moo - The only difference between mine and this is the `HAVING` clause, with a `MIN() <> MAX()` possibly being more intuitive and `COUNT(DISTINCT) = 2` being easier to extend to longer lists.  Well, and that Tim types much faster than I do and posted first, and wrote a demo, and is seemingly super-human :)

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Use a temp table to get all articles with titles.

Step 2: If an article occurs multiple times in your temp table, that means it has great and awesome as titles.

Try:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE MyTempTable (
    select t1.id_article, t2.title
    from table1 t1
    inner join table3 t3 on t3.id_article = t1.id_article
    inner join table2 t2 on t2.id_tag = t3.id_tag
)

select m.id_article
from MyTempTable m
group by m.id_article
having count(*)>1
```

Edit: This solution assumes there are two possible tags, great and awesome. If more, please add a "where" clause to the select query for creating the temp table like `where t2.title in ('great','awesome')`

Comment: Assumes that the tags only ever contain `great` and `awesome`.  If `reasonable` also exists or is added, this breaks.  Also assumes that no article can have the same tag twice; if one article has two `great` tags, this would treat it the same as having `great` And `awesome`.

Comment: @MatBailie You are right, updated my answer. If there is multiple "great" or "awesome" tags possible for table3, which I'd say a bad design, the counting must be updated with SUM like -> sum (case when m.title in ('great','awesome') then 1 else 0 end)

Comment: If you and I both vote an article to be great, then there could be two records making the same association.  It might not be a bad design, it might be an over simplified example.  *(Also, the `SUM(CASE)` that you propose would still give the same result.  You just need a `COUNT(DISTINCT id_tag)` somewhere.)*